# When does a 2D histogram / heatmap take a circular shape?

Tags: protein-structure, homework

[image]

The above is a 2D histogram of y and z internal coordinates describing the positions of C-alpha atoms involved in hydrogen bonds between antiparallel Beta-strands.

There is no color coding. It is given as it is.

What can we assume about the data points if a histogram is circular?

When does a histogram take a circular shape?

*[Note: "[2D histogram](https://plotly.com/python/2D-Histogram/)" is a synonym for what bioinformaticians typically call heat maps, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42262754/459780)]*